# Why is the quality of GIF animation from Photoshop so much better than Flash CS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, gif, image-quality, adobe-flash

When I create an animation and export it from Flash CS directly, the quality makes it heartbreaking to look at.

Even if I export it to a png sequence with good quality, and import it to Flash CS then export it, the result is also disappointing.

But if I try Photoshop with the png sequence, I find the result so amazing.

Why is there so much difference with default export settings?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include examples? It's hard to picture what the difference is when only described as disappointing/heartbreaking vs amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried smoothing the image? In the library panel in flash, right-click on your image and select 'properties'. In the options tab make sure that 'allow smoothing' it checked.[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I try to get a animated  gif by using "Publish", and the quality much better than "Export".That's very good, but I still can't understand the difference between "Publish" and "Export"~